# Mysql return rows before that are before current date and time

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that looks something like this:

```
itemNumber  mainDate      deliverTime
654         2019-12-16    7:30 AM
659         2019-12-16    9:30 PM
672         2019-12-17    10:30 AM
679         2019-12-17    5:00 PM
```

Current time  during the time of posting the question is `2019-12-17  1:13 PM`

I want to return all rows that are before this time, so I did:

```
select itemNumber,mainDate,deliverTime from invTable
where mainDate < Current_Date()
```

This gives me all record before today that has the main date of `2019-12-16`

To return all the items that are of today but the time has already passed I tried to do:

```
select itemNumber,mainDate,deliverTime from invTable
where mainDate < Current_Date() 
OR (mainDate = current_Date() and deliverTime <= current_time())
```

This gives an error:

> Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT)
>   and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '<='

Comment: You shouldn't use a string datatype for dates and times, use `DATE` and `TIME`. Or combine them into a single column with type `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems to indicate that the `deliverTime` column is not `TIME` datatype,  but is probably stored as `VARCHAR`.  (That's just a guess; and I'm not going to guess around at what datatypes of the columns are.)

Consider this:

```
SELECT t.itemnumber
     , t.maindate
     , t.delivertime
     , TIME(STR_TO_DATE(t.delivertime, '%h:%i %p')) AS tm
     , t.maindate + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(STR_TO_DATE(t.delivertime,'%h:%i %p'))) SECOND AS deliver_datetime
     , DATE(NOW())
     , TIME(NOW())
 FROM ( SELECT '654' AS itemnumber, '2019-12-16' + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS maindate, '7:30 AM' AS delivertime 
        UNION ALL SELECT '659','2019-12-16','9:30 PM'
        UNION ALL SELECT '672','2019-12-17','10:30 AM'
        UNION ALL SELECT '679','2019-12-17','5:00 PM'
      ) t
```

Note the use of the `STR_TO_DATE`, `TIME`, `TIME_TO_SEC` functions in expressions that convert from strings into `DATETIME` and `TIME` datatypes.

To get a condition in a WHERE clause that returns rows that have the combination of `maindate` and `delivertime` before `NOW()`, we could do something like this:

```
 WHERE t.maindate <= DATE(NOW())
   AND t.maindate + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(STR_TO_DATE(t.delivertime,'%h:%i %p'))) SECOND 
       <= NOW()
```

or we could do something like this:

```
 WHERE t.maindate <= DATE(NOW())
   AND ( t.maindate < DATE(NOW()) OR TIME(STR_TO_DATE(v.delivertime, '%h:%i %p')) < TIME(NOW()) )
```

---

This is just a couple of possible query patterns, working with the separate DATE and TIME (stored as string) components.

The normative pattern would be to store the date and time components into a *single* column with `DATETIME` datatype.

Storing those together into a single `deliver_datetime` column, the condition in the WHERE clause would be something like:

```
 WHERE t.deliver_datetime <= NOW()
```

Where there is a specific performance need to store just the `TIME` portion separately, then we could also do that.

---